# ActionBar.TabListener activity loads tabs in advance

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm writing an android application and my main activity implements `ActionBar.TabListener`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
    //class implementaion
}
```

I have several tabs and everything works fine, but there is a little problem. When a user scrolls tabs, the next tab's fragment is being loaded in advance. For example if user opens application it loads 1st and 2nd tabs, then user switches to 2nd tab and it loads 3rd tab and so on.

Now, why are tabs being loaded in advance and is there a way not to do it? Because each tab has lot of data and there is no need to load whole thing if that tab is not the current one.